# A 1024x1024 app store icon is required by iOS apps (WatchKit)

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I've started to experience a problem with Xcode 9.1(9B55). On my last archive to submit to the app store, it is now complaining about the 1024x1024 app store icon on my WatchKit app.

Even tho I have added the correct iphone weeks ago, and has been working for every other submit.

I have deleted the app icon,re-added; even created a new png version to see if it was a transparency issue. Nothing will work, it keeps saying I am missing it.

I've even gone ahead and deleted the AppIcon which stores all sizes, and redid the whole thing.

Every size warning disappears when I add the icon, except 1024x1024.

What am I missing here, could this be a Xcode 9 bug?

> Missing App Store Icon - WatchOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App
>   Store Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset
>   Catalog or via iTunes Connect, apps cannot be submitted for App Review
>   or Beta App Review. Refer to
>   https://developer.apple.com/watchos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/home-screen-icons/
>   for more information.1

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your AppIcons.xcassets file in Xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the release notes of Xcode 9.1, it seems this is a known issue.

- Known Issues

  - WatchKit App Store icons in the asset catalog are not uploaded when using Xcode to submit an app to the App Store. (33383969)

    - *Workaround*: Use the iTunes Connect web app to upload WatchKit App Store icons.